# Random number generator issues in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, random

My intention here is just to fill up an array with numbers in order from 1, to a random number between 1 and 1000. However, after repeatedly running this code (about 50 times), the highest number I have gotten is 120, and only twice has it been over 100. The majority of my arrays were anywhere between 0 and 60. This behavior appears off to me. Am I doing something wrong?

```
my_array = []
i = 0
while i <= rand(1000)
    my_array << i 
    i += 1  
end

puts my_array.count
puts my_array
```

Comment: Are you seeding your randomizer?

Comment: You're random number is the guard in the while loop and you are appending what you thought to be the counter.

Comment: After looking at my code... does this run a new random number every time it loops? If so, that would explain why it leans so heavily toward smaller numbers. I am going to check and then report back if no one has answered yet.

Comment: I would expect `rand(1000)` to be evaluated every time the conditional is evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is broken, because you're checking versus the random number. Do this:

```
(0..1000).collect{ rand(1000) }
```

This will return an array of one thousand random numbers.

Or, closer to your code:

```
my_array = []
i = 0
while i <= 1000
    my_array << rand(1000) 
    i += 1  
end
```

As per comment, what you want is:

```
(1..rand(1000))

(1..rand(1000)).to_a
```

The first results in a range, which is "easier to carry around", the second results in the populated array.

(Edit) Note:

`(1..10)` is inclusive - `(1..10).to_a == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

`(1...10)` is partially exclusive - `(1...10).to_a == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` - it does not include the end of the array, but still includes the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually trying to get an array from 1 to some random number between 1 and 1000, in sequential order.

Comment: @Kewigro There is no order with random.  If you want it sequential, you'll have to sort it after.

Comment: In Ruby, you are generally describing what you want, rather than the recipe for getting it. What you want is an array from 1 to a random number, so that's what you write.

Comment: Okay. I'm just learning ruby. Your examples helped to highlight the mistake I was making, which i had suspected but wasn't sure how to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want:

```
(1...rand(1000)).to_a
```

Comment: Or even without `#to_a`. For most applications things that include Enumerable are as good as arrays.

Comment: Ok but OP specifically asked for an array.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I have amended my code to reflect what I was trying to accomplish initially. My problem was that every time I looped through my code I generated a new random number. Because of this, as 'i' incremented toward 1000 it became more and more likely that a random number would be generated that was lower than 'i'. My fix, while not as elegant as the solution above that I accepted, was to store the random number in a variable, BEFORE attempting to use it in a loop. Thanks again. Here is the amended code:

```
my_array = []
i = 0
g = rand(1000)
while i <= g
    my_array << i 
    i += 1  
end

puts my_array.count
puts my_array
```

Comment: You could do this less verbosely as `my_array = (1..g).to_a`

Comment: Yes, that looks very nice. I will use that instead from now on.